# rails 4 with devise, order of routes definition makes redirection loop with redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I was doing a sample project with devise, and have this on my routes:

```
resources :admins
devise_for :admins
```

It causes a redirection loop. I changed the order of the lines to look like:

```
devise_for :admins
resources :admins
```

And then it worked.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified and both `resources` and `devise_for` are shorthand for multiple routes. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) is a list of routes generated by resources and [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for) is a list of the one's generated by Devise.

I can't answer what's specifically causing the redirect loop without knowing all of the '-able' devise categories you have (confirmable, recoverable etc.), but it seems like the problem would be the two POST routes generated for creating a new admin. This is why it's generally considered best practice not to use resources in the routes.

If you want to know for sure you can run `rake routes` in your terminal to see all the routes that those resources have made, identify any potential duplicates and then put those duplicates behind an `except:` in the resources to see if you've caught the problem :

```
resources :admins, except: :create
devise_for :admins
```